# ID for local client using sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets

I want get unique ID for my client connected by a server. I have many clients, but, each one want has one different ID. An close solution is similar to this:

```
Socket cliente = servidor.accept();

        System.out.println("New connection with" +   
        cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
        String addr = servidor.getLocalSocketAddress().toString();
        ThreadServidor ts = new ThreadServidor(addr, cliente); 
        ts.start();
```

The clients have the same code to connect:

```
  Socket conexao = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12345);
```

I need the information of the own client ip and port connected too.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following methods can be called on your socket `cliente` to get the local and remote IP addresses and the local and remote ports.

```
getLocalAddress()
getLocalPort()
getInetAddress() // gets the remote address
getPort() // gets the remote port
```

The combination of all that information is unique.

More info at the Javadoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Comment: As the local IP:port is always the same for any given server you can leave them out.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().` It embodies the remote host:port, which is all you need at the server end.